# How do i join two queries and then paginate

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-paginate

```
    $data = Category::join('articles', function ($join) {
       $join->on('categories.id', 'articles.category_id')
        ->where('categories.type', 'news')
        ->where('articles.status', '1');
    })->get()->sortByDesc('updated_at')->paginate(5);
```

I have 2 variables both querying the same model. I want to now merge these 2 separate datasets into a variable called $articles and then paginate on it.

Comment: Just remove get() and your query should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the get() method from the code like:

```
$data = Category::join('articles', function ($join) {
    $join->on('categories.id', 'articles.category_id')
    ->where('categories.type', 'news')
    ->where('articles.status', '1');
})->sortByDesc('updated_at')->paginate(5);
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

When joining queries and paginate in controller, to view the output in paginate you should include this under you for loop output:

```
{{ $data->links() }}
```